# CSS real "slide" toggle not "height" toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been looking around for a while but did not find a solution for what I am trying to create.

I would like to have a real "slide" toggle, so a div is "moving down in". But if you take JQuery slideToggle or several CSS solutions I found, they just modify the height of a div, they don't really slide it.

So I created my own solution by animating the margin-top property, which works nicely, however I have a problem with dynamic heights (for example if you resize the browser-window), not sure how high the negative margin-top should be to make sure it is always fully slided out, and on the other side do not delay the slide-in because the margin-top is too far out.

I currently use

```
margin-top: -100%;
```

however, if you resize the window/frame, it's not always enough negative margin.

Maybe there is already a better solution out there but I just did not find it, so I created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzj80kzs/1/), to share my idea and hear you suggestions.

**UPDATE:** My latest [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzj80kzs/9/) is here ... changed a few things, thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: You say you looked for alternatives, and none of them were for your taste. So you created your own. As I see, it works pretty well and makes the job done. What else do you need?

Comment: My problem has been the dynamic height part of my first approach, on small viewport width the details did not fully slide out, on high width and high negative margin, the animation was way to quick. However my latest update now works the way I wanted it to. Hope it helps if someone is looking for the same. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks for all your inspirations**, it finally led me to this solution and I think it is quite nice.

With this new apporach I switched to using "slideToggle", so basically now it is a height toggle again (which I did not want), but I used a "trick" to create the optical slide effect I wanted to achieve. Inside the details DIV, I added a pinned DIV that sticks to the bottom of the parent. So as the height of the parent grows, the content is "slided" in now, not just "revealed".

The only problem that came up has been, that the pinned DIV is positioned absolute, so the parent did not have a height anymore, and I wanted the details to be invisible at start. So I decided to grab the height with JQuery from the pinned DIV, and add it to the details DIV.

Because JQuery doesn't "like" hidden Elements when trying to get the height, I am now getting the height of the "pinned details" with the help of the nice "JQuery Actual Plugin" by Ben Lin.

```
    $('.details').each(function(){
      $(this).height($(this).find('.pinned').actual('height'));
    });
```

I added an additional trigger in my latest fiddle so that the height still matches if the Window is resized.

In the end this solution is what I wanted to achieve optically. Take a look at my [final fidde](http://jsfiddle.net/jzj80kzs/9/) if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE - fix typo and tidy up.

I think you can use it in combination with jQuery `show()` and `hide()` to the code to avoid the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/jzj80kzs/7/

```
$('.switch').click(function(event) {
  var theSwitch = $(this).closest('.block').find('.switch');
  var theBlock = $(this).closest('.block').find('.details');
  if (theBlock.hasClass('mt0')) {
    theSwitch.html('+ show');  // change the switch dynamically
    theBlock.removeClass('mt0').slideUp(function() {
      $(this).delay(300).hide();
    });
  } else {
    theSwitch.html('- hide');
    theBlock.addClass('mt0').slideDown().show();
  }
});
```

```js
$('.switch').click(function(event) {
  var theSwitch = $(this).closest('.block').find('.switch');
  var theBlock = $(this).closest('.block').find('.details');
  if (theBlock.hasClass('mt0')) {
    theSwitch.html('+ show'); // change the switch dynamically
    theBlock.removeClass('mt0').slideUp(function() {
      $(this).delay(300).hide();
    });
  } else {
    theSwitch.html('- hide');
    theBlock.addClass('mt0').slideDown().show();
  }
});
```

```css
div.block {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
div.block:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
div.basics {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}
div.details {
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #99F;
  z-index: 1;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -100%;
  -webkit-transition: margin-top 600ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  -moz-transition: margin-top 600ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  -o-transition: margin-top 600ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  transition: margin-top 600ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
}
div.mt0 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
span.switch {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="basics">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <span class="switch">+ show</span>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
    takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="basics">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <span class="switch">+ show</span>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
    takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="basics">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <span class="switch">+ show</span>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
    takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="basics">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <span class="switch">+ show</span>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
    takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code will throw numerous errors because `slideUp` and `slideDown` are not capitalized correctly. Capitalizing them as shown here will fix this problem.

Comment: This solution (with the capitalization) has a bad side effect, it destroys the slide I wanted to create, when I tested it, the slide in worked on first click, the slide-out did not appear anymore but the details somehow where hidden instantly, and on the next slide in, the slideDown (height-change) replaced the original slide-in.

Comment: @Sunny I modified the answer.

Comment: @IsabelHM Yes, thanks, I tried it, works nicely now, howerver, the problem stays thesame, the "content slide" does only appear on first click, afterwards only the "height slide" takes place, so basically one could completely remove the add/remove Class functions here, because they are simply ignored somehow.

If you check out my latest fiddle, I took a different approach, based on sildeToggle (so a height-toggle too), but added the content to a div that is pinned to the bottom of the details-container, which generates the optical slide effect that I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good thing to use `max-height` instead of `margin-top` and you can use `transition-duration`

```
 div.block {
         position: relative;
         overflow: hidden;
         border: 1px solid #333;
         border-bottom: 0px;
         line-height: 20px;         
         background-color: #fff;
     }
         div.block:last-child {
             border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
         }
     div.basics {
         position:relative;
         background-color: #fff;
         z-index: 2;
         padding: 2px 4px;
     }
     div.details {
         border-top: 1px solid #333;
         position: relative;
         background-color: #99F;
         z-index: 1;
         height: auto;
         max-height: 0px;
         transition-duration: 0.5s;
     }
     div.mt0 {
         max-height: 1000px;
         transition-duration: 0.5s;
     }
     span.switch {
         float: right;
         cursor: pointer;
         font-size: 20px;
         font-weight: bold;
     }
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jzj80kzs/3/)

Comment: Max-Height is basically the same as I would use JQuery slideToggle, the height is animated, not the div-position. So it does not work for my "optical" approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. It should slide up and down smoothly every time the button is clicked. I put the `show`/`hide` function in the `slideUp`/`slideDown` callback, which should prevent the sudden snapping.

```
$('.switch').click(function() {                            
    if ($(this).closest('.block').find('.details').hasClass('mt0')) {
        $(this).closest('.block').find('.details').removeClass('mt0');
        $(this).closest('.block').find('.details').slideUp(function(){$(this).hide();});
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.block').find('.details').addClass('mt0');
        $(this).closest('.block').find('.details').slideDown(function(){$(this).show();});
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/806eda2o/1/

Comment: Thanks for this hint, yes, it prevents the sudden snapping, however the final effect is thesame, the "slide" of the content only works on the first click, afterwards just the "height" is changed, the CSS transition is ignored. :(

I finally created an approach that works perfectly ... unfortunately it is a total "content overkill" because everything is "doubled", because auto-height and absolute positioning do not work.

So here's my overkill fiddle. :)
http://jsfiddle.net/jzj80kzs/4/

Comment: Congratulations on working it out on your own! That's one of the primary things SO is for: Using hints and recommendations to reach the correct answer yourself. Just FYI, you can avoid having to manually duplicate the html in the `.pinned` element by adding this: `$(".pinned").each(function(){$(this).html($(this).siblings('.spacer').html());});` http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/jzj80kzs/10/

Comment: Thank you! Quite useful your addition. As later on my data is generated with PHP and mySQL the duplication would not be "manual", however this function is quite interesting.
However, as you can see in my latest fiddle, I could get rid of the duplicate content at all, by adding height-measures via JQuery, I think that should be the better solution considering traffic and loading time.